# What are the steps to claim my XTZ account?

Tags: fundraiser

Could someone please provide clear step-by-step instructions on how users can claim their XTZ from the fundraiser ? This would be a good reference article for many.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also do it via the tezos-client.

Step 1) Get your activation key here: https://tezos.com/get-started/

Step 2 *Optional*, if you don't have a node set up: https://github.com/tezoscommunity/FAQ/blob/master/Compile_Mainnet.md

Step 3)

```
 cd into Tezos

./tezos-client add address my_account <public key hash from donation PDF>

./tezos-client activate fundraiser account my_account with <activation key from verification site>

./tezos-client import fundraiser secret key my_account
```

Comment: Some complementary info is also available on the tezos official doc: http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/introduction/various.html#activate-fundraiser-account

Answer (score 3):

Some answer is available on reddit, perhaps it's a good start

https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/8v9ep0/steps_to_claim_your_xtz_account_and_delegate/

> 1 Activate your wallet
>
> a. Go to https://activate.tezos.com/
>
> b. Enter your Public Key Hash/Address
>
> c. Enter your activation code
>
> d. Click Activate Wait for 30 seconds for your wallet to get activated. 
>   Note :- if you get an error than change your browser
>
> 2.Restore your wallet
>
> a. Goto https://wallet.tezbox.com/
>
> b. Click on restore your wallet
>
> c. Click the fundraiser wallet on top right and enter the details (15 words seed, password, activation code and email)
>
> d. Click on restore Tezos. (Done!)
>
> e. Next page will ask you to enter a password to encrypt your wallet. (You can use any password you want)
>
> Note:- Compare your public Hash address of ICO wallet with the wallet you have entered. If the address does not match or balance is 0 than you have either not activated your wallet (Step 1) or entered something wrong (Repeat Step 2)
>
> 3 Delegate your coins
>
> a. Go to www.mytezosbaker.com to see potential delegates. Choose a  delegate and go to their confirm their delegate address.
>
> b. On your wallet page (Tezbox wallet as mentioned in step 2) click on add
>   account (on left side). This will add an account address starting from
>   K........ Please remember that this address is under your control. You
>   won't need a seperate keys for it. You cannot delegate from your T
>   address. You can only delegate from K address
>
> c. Transfer your coins from T address to K address (created in step 2)
>
> d. Under the delegation options in K address choose the delegate. You can select
>   the already entered delegator in drop down menu or enter a new one in
>   custom field.

Comment: Tezos Community published a video of this process as well.  You can watch it here:  https://www.useloom.com/share/70173a52088c49deaff3c2cc4daeb007