# How do I get access to my tezos coins

Tags: wallets

I would like to ask your help to get access to my tezos coins.  The issue is that my assistant bought the coins at placement and then she left me and I have no communication with her nor have access to the coins.  I continue receiving updates on my email account so I am confident the coins are still there.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Do you have the PDF file from the fundraiser? Do you remember what password was used?

Comment: I only have access to the email used for registration

Comment: The PDF and the password are essential to claim the XTZ linked to the fundraiser. There is no way to recover these from a third party since you are the only custodian of those as per the T&C of the fundraiser. Your best bet is probably to try to get contact with the person who contributed on your behalf.

Answer (score 1):

To claim your Tezos from the fundraiser you need the following information that was provided in the PDF during the fundraiser (assuming you were not taking part via Bitcoinsuisse):

1. The 15 words seed phrase that can be found on the PDF
2. The password that was used for the fundraiser
3. The email address that was used during the fundraiser
4. Your public key - (should begin with "tz1")

Without the seed phrase from your PDF nothing can be done. If you lost your password, you might be able to bruteforce it.

Once you obtained the data, follow the steps described here: https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/28/463

Answer (score 0):

You indicated you do not have the the PDF file and associated password from the fundraiser. Unfortunately, without these, you cannot recover your funds.