# activate Fundraiser account

Tags: account, transfer, fundraiser

I am using XTZ for wallet service, when I create an empty Mnemonic account to receive value, I find received value can not be transferred; I am confusing where could I find a Fundraiser account on the main net to transfer value.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/27/what-are-the-steps-to-claim-my-xtz-account

Answer (score 1):

Your non-activate Tez (not tezzie), are not visible on the chain. You must activate your ICO account first. https://activate.tezos.com/ You will need the original PDF, email, and password from the ICO. You can then use any webwallet that supports activation to activate your ICO funds.